# Can MemberConverter read a @mention in server as an id?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord import commands

@client.command()
async def check(current, content: str, member: commands.MemberConverter):
    status = None
    for member in current.guild.members:
        if str(member.mention) == content:
            status = member.status
            break
```

it returns with an error when i type `#check @mention` in the server,

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: member is a required argument that is missing.
```

do anyone knows why it's missing?

Comment: you are giving the member arg in the place of the content arg

Comment: where should i put the member arg in?

Comment: #check content @mention

Comment: is there a way to make the command only `#check @mention`, I didn't want it to do double `#check content @mention`

Comment: then your command won't work

Comment: Then change the position of the mention, (ctx, member, content) should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code currently expects two arguments:

- content of type string
- member of any type a member can be, e.g. mention

From your post, as far as I understood it, you only want to pass *one argument*, namely the member. Therefore your code would need to look like this:

```py
import discord
from discord import commands

@client.command()
async def check(current, searched_member: commands.MemberConverter):
    status = None
    for member in current.guild.members:
        if member.id == searched_member.id:
            status = member.status
            break
```

Changes:

- I removed the "content" argument from the function, as it is not needed
- I changed the "member" argument name by "searched_member" as you already use the variable name "member" when iterating through the guild members
- I changed the comparison to be between the two ids, as the member converter *already returns a member object*. IDs are just the easiest way to make sure you're talking about the same member.

Now speaking of which, because the member converter *already returns a member object* the entire process of looping through the guild members is *completely unnecessary*. Just get the status directly from the member object:

```py
import discord
from discord import commands

@client.command()
async def check(current, searched_member: commands.MemberConverter):
    status = searched_member.status
```

Comment: thank you so much! it finally worked, I was first confused on how to call mentioned member instead of copying their id.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `message.mentions[0]` this wil grab the mentioned member from a message

Comment: I changed `if str(member.message.mentions[0])`  however it still shows the error